# git: move commit before merge

Tags: git, merge

My history tree currently looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to apply commit `b3` to branch master. Of course I could merge again branch `feature` into `master` but history will look messy with two merge commits (`a6`, and `a4` that is just useless now):
[image]

---

Thus, what I'd like to know, is **how to make `a4` now point on `b3` instead of `b2`?**
[image]
<sub>I acknowledge `SHA1`s will be different, and thus commits will be renamed `a4'` and `a5'`</sub>

Comment: From master, do `git rebase -p b3`. That should preserve the merge but move it after `b3`.

Comment: @poke thx! Should I be on `a4` state to do this, or is it working if I'm on `a5`?

Comment: It should work on either of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the master branch, you can simply rebase onto the new `b3` while preserving merges using the [`--preserve-merges` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) (or `-p` in short):

```
git rebase -p feature
```

That way, when Git rebases, it will not attempt to flatten the merge, but instead recreate it on top of the new base commit. So your history will look like this:

```
                               master
                                 ↓
a1 -- a2 -- a3 --------- a4' -- a5'
        \                /
         \              /
          b1 -- b2 -- b3
                      ↑
                   feature
```

Compared to the following when not using the `--preserve-merges` flag:

```
                                      master
                                        ↓
a1 -- a2                 a3' -- a4' -- a5'
        \                /
         \              /
          b1 -- b2 -- b3
                      ↑
                   feature
```

Comment: OP should (and, I see, did) note that the result is a new (different) merge, with different hash and different tree.  As you say, rebase re-*creates* (i.e., make a *new*) merge that supplants the old one.  Anyway, upvoted. :-)

Comment: @torek Yeah, I use the `x'` notion to denote that it’s a recreated commit based on the original `x` :)